# Why is my function looking for an input with the exact same name instead of working with the variable I passed?

Tags: r, function

test is a function to check if an object exists in the global environment, is not empty, and belongs to a particular class.

```
test <- function(foo, response=TRUE) {
    if (missing(foo)) {
        response <- FALSE
    }
    if (response) {
        if (!exists(as.character(substitute(foo)), envir = .GlobalEnv)) {
            response <- FALSE
        }
    }
    if (response) {
        response <- ifelse(class(foo) != "numeric", FALSE, TRUE)
    }
return(response)
}
```

Now in `foobar` and a dozen other functions, I want to make sure `foo` is the right kind of object I want before proceeding with anything else.

```
foobar <- function(foo)
{
    if(test(foo)) {
    cat ("Yes, I have foo! \n")
    }
    if(!test(foo)) {
        cat("Sorry, not a valid foo")
    }
}

 >ls()
[1] "foobar" "test"
 >test(a)
[1] FALSE
 >a <- "foobar"
 >test(a)
[1] FALSE
 >a <- 1
 >test(a)
[1] TRUE
 >foobar(a)
Sorry, not a valid foo
 >
# what the???
 >ls()
[1] "a"      "foobar" "test"
 >foo <- 1
 >foobar(foo)
Yes, I have foo!
 >
```

Comment: I think it's because you're nesting the `substitute`s - a bit like if you wrote a function `f <- function(x) library(x)` and tried `f(MASS)`. I've never found a solution to this though.

Answer (score 3):

Objects loose their original names when handed off more than once. The copies get assigned new localnames. You need to grab the name on the first pass and then test with ls()

```
 foobar <- function(foo)
 { fooname <- deparse(substitute(foo)); print(fooname)
     if(test(fooname) ) {
     cat ("Yes, I have foo! \n")
     }
     if(!test(fooname) ) {
         cat("Sorry, not a valid foo")
     }
 }

 test <- function(foo, response=TRUE) { 
     if (missing(foo)) {
         response <- FALSE
                        }
     if (response) {
         if ( foo %in% ls( envir = .GlobalEnv) ) {
             response <- TRUE }else {response <- FALSE}
                                                }

 return(response)
                                      }
 foobar(after)
# [1] "after"
#Yes, I have foo!
```

Answer (score 2):

To verify, the problem is in the fact that the `substitute` is nested.

When R looks at `foobar(a)`, it runs `test(foo)` *within* the `foobar` function, and so the variable that the `test` function looks at is called `foo`.

I'll start with a toy example to make things easier to explain. The `library` function, like your `test` function, interprets its argument via the variable name. i.e. `library(MASS)` loads the 'MASS' library, not the string that is contained inside the variable 'MASS'.

Now I'll make a function `f` that just calls `library` - this mirrors your `foobar` function:

```
f <- function(x) {
    library(x)
}
```

Now let's try:

```
> f(MASS)
Error in library(x) : there is no package called ‘x’
```

Oh no! It didn't work! How come? Because remember, *within* the `library` code, it *substitutes* the variable passed in. i.e. `library <- function(lib,...) substitute(lib)`.

So `f(MASS)` goes to `function(x) library(x)`, and hence it's like I typed `library(x)` straight into the command line -- `library` is only trying to load `x`, and not x's *value*, `MASS`.

OK, we can fix this: we just need to change `library(x)` to `library(substitute(x))`, since `substitute(x)` is `MASS` and we'll then end up with `library(MASS)`, right?

```
f <- function(x) {
    library(substitute(x))
}
```

Let's try:

```
> f(MASS)
Error in library(substitute(x)) : 'package' must be of length 1
```

Urgh, what happened? Within `f`, the `substitute(x)` is **not being evaluated**, because `library` *purposefully* doesn't evaluate the expression it gets fed, because then typing `library(MASS)` in the command line wouldn't work.

So we really want to save `substitute(x)` as a variable and then perform `library` on that variable.

The only problem is that even if we do `y <- substitute(x); library(y)` within `f`, we always run into this problem that *the argument fed into `library` is never evaluated*. So doing this will cause the same as the first error: 'there is no package called `y`'.

How can we fix this? We need to somehow *indirectly* call `library` with `substitute(x)` as the argument, where `substitute(x)` is *evaluated*.

Aha! We can use `do.call`! (note: I didn't come up with this on my own, I was guided by [this post to the R mailing list on nested substitutes](https://mailman.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-February/304214.html):

```
f <- function(x) {
    do.call(library,list(substitute(x)))
}
```

This does *exactly* what we want - it calls `library` but passes `substitute(x)` in as the library. It *evaluates* `substitute(x)` first, since we haven't directly written `library(substitute(x))`. nifty right?

```
> f(MASS) # no error!
# see if MASS is loaded - check if function 'lda' is there:
> exists('lda',mode='function') 
[1] TRUE # huzzah!
```

#### Solution for your case

So, applying this lesson to your question, try:

```
foobar <- function(foo)
{
    if ( do.call(test,list(substitute(foo))) ) # see the do.call & substitute?
        cat ("Yes, I have foo! \n")
    else
        cat("Sorry, not a valid foo")
}
```

Let's see:

```
> ls()
[1] "foobar" "test"  
> test(a)
[1] FALSE
> a <- 'foobar'
> test(a)
[1] FALSE
> a <- 1
> test(a)
[1] TRUE
> foobar(a)
Yes, I have foo!
```

Huzzah! (by the way: thanks for asking this question, because the answer is something I've always wanted to know).